# sanitize user input on client side using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm already handle the sanitization in my server side, any improper input text like `<script>alert('hi')</script>` can be handle properly. But because I also pass around data using websocket, so this part is broken if user send

```
<script>alert('hi')</script>
```

I found encodeURIComponent but confused with encodeURI, which one is for xss handling in client side?

Comment: encodeURI() will not encode: `~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'` 
encodeURIComponent() will not encode: `~!*()'` now you decide! . But can you really trust client side?

Comment: For XSS Sanitization have a look at Yahoo's [xss-filters](https://github.com/yahoo/xss-filters) library or at [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify).

Answer (score 3):

For XSS Sanitization have a look at Yahoo's [xss-filters](https://github.com/yahoo/xss-filters) library or at [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify).

Here an example using DOMPurify:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input'),
    result = document.getElementById('result'),
    button = document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
      // Sanitize
      var clean = DOMPurify.sanitize(input.value, {SAFE_FOR_TEMPLATES: true});

      result.innerHTML = clean;
      console.log(clean);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dompurify/0.8.4/purify.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input"> 
<button id="button">Send</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: I used `var isValid = ($('input').val().indexOf('<script'>') >-1) ? false : true; `Can I?

Comment: Don't think so.. Suppose as one example that someone writes: `<script type="text/javascript">alert('hi')</script>`

Comment: I know, so just `indexOf('script')`

Comment: If someone type: "I would like to make a new script"??

Comment: then it will be invalid :P

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), then you can convert every character to entities.

```js
function sanitize(a) {
  var b = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b += "&#x"+a.charCodeAt(i).toString(16)+";"
  }
  return b;
}
```

```html
User Input:
<input type="textbox" id="box">
<input type="button" value="Sanitize to entities" onclick="document.getElementById('sanitizedfield').innerText=(sanitize(document.getElementById('box').value))"><pre id="sanitizedfield"></pre>
```

Comment: It changes characters also, not desired.